# Graylog alert condition based on field value

Tags: graylog

I tried Graylog Community forum but no response from there, so I am asking Stackoverflow for help.

I need to setup a Graylog alert based on field value greater than certain threshold. for example, my message:
“sample alert, age: 100”
I want to get an alert when age > 60.  (you can assume age extractor is setup and age is converted to numeric value)

There’s this aggregate condition in alert but it does aggregation across multiple messages. What I need is much simpler than that,

Is this possible? How could I do that?

Notes:
My Graylog version v2.4.6

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

There is no alert condition you can use to check if *any* message contains a field > n. The workaround for this would be to setup a stream that contains all messages where a field is > n and then use the message count condition on that stream to alert on any incoming message.